# Java - Convert a string of multiple characters to just a string of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string coords that looks like this: "(1,2)-(5,7)"

How would I go about converting this string to an array: [1, 2, 5, 7]?

I have other strings with two digit values, for example: "(13,26)-(1,16)"

This needs to become [13, 26, 1, 16]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you done in your attempt to achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

```
String s = "(1,2)-(45,87)";
String[] splitted = s.replaceFirst("\\D+", "").split("\\D+"); // Outputs: [1, 2, 45, 87]
```

### Explanation:

`\\D++` - means one or more non-digit characters

`s.replaceFirst("\\D+", "")` - this is needed to avoid storing empty String at the first index of `splitted` array (if there is a "delimited" at the first index of input String, String.split() method treats beginning of the String as the first element to store in result array. With that replaceFirst() method, you get rid of all non-digit characters present at the very beginning of input String.

`.split("\\D+")` - split the result from the previous operation on one or more non-digit characters.

*Note:* If you would use just `String[] splitted = s.split("\\D+");` (without replaceFirst() part, output would look like this: `[, 1, 2, 45, 87]`, what was not your intention.

Answer (score 0):

//your string

```
String x = "(13,26)-(5,7)";
```

//into string array

```
String arr[] = x.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", ",").split(",");
```

If you don't want string array and you want string then:

```
x.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", ",");
```

and you can append "[" and "]" if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try something like:

```
String array = "(1,2)-(5,7)";

String[] items = arr.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "").replaceAll("-","").split(",");

int[] newArray = new int[items.length];

for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will parse the values out for you if you just need to match 1 to 2 digits at a time:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class IntegerGetter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "(13,26)-(1,16)"; // Line with the values

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,2}");  // Create a regex pattern searching number values between 0 and 99
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    while(m.find()) {
        values.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));  // Convert the String matches to integers
    }

    System.out.println("Values are: " + Arrays.toString(values.toArray()));
}
}
```